# Store views having different URL structures

Tags: multistore, url, store-view

I have a webshop with different store views for different languages.
www.clothing.com and www.english.clothing.com for example.

My problem is that they have different link structures, so if I'm in a category and want to change language i get the 404 page. For example if i choose a category it will go to www.clothing.com/shirt. If I then change language it will look for www.english.clothing.com/shirt which doesn't exist.

If I choose the same category while I'm on the english page it will go to www.english.clothing.com/catalog/category/view/s/shirt/id/3/

How can i change this?

Note: if I choose a product in that category and change language it works as it should.

Comment: it can catalog url indexing.reidexing it

Comment: @AmitBera : Please post it as an answer so that McKeene can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

McKeene,This type of issue may create for below issue:

`Indexing issue with catalog_url_rewrite(Most of case).` for this goto admin Index management for indexing